# Change perspective UIImageView with accelerometer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, perspective

I search a way on iOS to change the perspective of a image with the data get by the accelerometer.

I use this but the result is not correct :

```
 self.picture.layer.transform =  CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90), x, y, z);
```

The purpose of this is to take a picture with the camera, get info from the accelerometer and add a picture overlay with the perspective taken on the camera.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Anybody to help me ? Do you see what i want to do ? 

Example : take a picture and show the distance of items compared to a center selecter by the user.